# Android - How to set a value for CheckBoxPreference? Or?

Tags: android, android-preferences, checkboxpreference

I'm building an app where I need to show a settings screen when user can check what items from which categories will be displayed in main activity's listview.

I'm parsing an XML for these categories, so the `PreferenceScreen` is done programatically and all the `CheckBoxPreferences` are build in a loop. Code:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.someurl.com/phone/categories.php");

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("category");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {                
        Element category = (Element)nodeList.item(i);

        Node id = category.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0);
        Node title = category.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0);

        CheckBoxPreference togglePref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
        togglePref.setKey("category_" + id.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
        togglePref.setDefaultValue(true);
        togglePref.setTitle(title.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
        root.addPreference(togglePref);
    }
} catch(Exception ex) {
    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), ex.getMessage());
}
```

where `root` is `PreferenceScreen` object.

My problem is that I need to store not only a title for one checkbox option but I also need to store an ID of the category but there is no such property in `CheckBoxPreference` object.

My question is if there is another workaround or should I extend the `CheckBoxPreference` class and create some custom `MyCheckBoxPreference` that will store also another "value"?

My vision is to have something similar (or same) as common HTML checkbox - while it has a value this is not set (submitted) if checkbox is not checked and on other hand when checked You obtain the concrete value instead of just true/false...

AFAIK the `CheckBoxPreference` has only state checked/unchecked while no value that could be returned.

I was thinking about having the preference keys set just to the ID of concrete cetagories instead of `category_<ID>` and then calling `sharedPreferences.getAll()` - I expect that only checked `CheckBoxPreferences` should be returned and then by obtaining of their keys I should be able to operate with the category IDs... Could this be an easy solution and good approach???

Many thanks for any proper advice!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that I need to store not only a title for one checkbox option but I also need to store an ID of the category but there is no such property in CheckBoxPreference object.

IMHO, that is what the key is for.

> I was thinking about having the preference keys set just to the ID of concrete cetagories instead of category_ and then calling sharedPreferences.getAll() - I expect that only checked CheckBoxPreferences should be returned and then by obtaining of their keys I should be able to operate with the category IDs... Could this be an easy solution and good approach???

You will get all `CheckBoxPreference` objects that have been touched by the user, whether they are checked or unchecked. This is probably the correct approach.

Comment: OK, I thought that the key is like a preference unique identifier, not it's value... But I'll give it a try...

Comment: @shadyyx: It is the preference unique identifier. However, for a boolean state, you need no other "value" than the identifier and whether or not it is checked.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it possible to change the state of checkbox based on a condition and not if the user clicks on it or not ?

Comment: @RainMan: Um, do you [mean `setChecked()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html#setChecked%28boolean%29)?

Comment: @CommonsWare the thing is that I want to use checkboxpreference for in app purchase, so if the purchase fails uncheck the box and if success check the box. But, no matter what I do, the box is checked even if the purchase fails. I asked a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475618/implement-in-app-billing-using-the-checkboxpreference). Any help will be appreciated.